# Здравствуйте! Хочу сделать чтобы при вводе в <input> поля формы на сайте, на yandex карте строился маршрут по начальной и конечной точке

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Хочу сделать чтобы при вводе в  поля  формы на сайте, на карте строился маршрут по начальной и конечной точке, как в примере https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator , подскажите как при заполнении родных input'ов передать значение на yandex карту

```php
        <main>
        <form action="index.php">
            <label for = "address_from">Откуда</label>
            <input class = "input" id="address_from" name="address_from" size="32" type="text" placeholder="Выберите место A">

            <label for = "address_to">Куда</label>
            <input class = "input" id="address_to" name="address_to" size="32" type="text" placeholder="Выберите место Б">
        </form>
        <div id="yandexMap" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
    </main>
```

```
$('#address_from').on('change', function(event){ 
    $address_from = ($(this).val())
});
$('#address_to').on('change', function(event){ 
    $address_to = ($(this).val())
});
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('yandexMap', {
    center: [55.355125, 86.087234],
        zoom: 11,
        controls: []
    }),
        routePanelControl = new ymaps.control.RoutePanel({
            options: {
                showHeader: false,
            }
        }),
        zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({
            options: {
                size: 'small',
                float: 'none',
                position: {
                    bottom: 145,
                    right: 10
                }
            }
        });
    routePanelControl.routePanel.options.set({
        types: {auto: true}
    });
    var _from = new ymaps.SuggestView('address_from');
    var _to = new ymaps.SuggestView('address_to');
    routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
        from: $address_from,
        to: $address_to
     });
    myMap.controls.add(routePanelControl).add(zoomControl);
};
```

Comment: Очевидно, нужно изучить документацию по [API Яндекс.Карт](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/) и использовать полученные знания для написания необходимого кода.

Comment: В документации нашел как задать начальную и конечную точку маршрута, но мне не удается передать через свои input'ы значения для этих полей

Comment: Покажите ваш [mcve] и подробно объясните, что именно значит "не удаётся".

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev обновил

Comment: Вы не обновляете состояние панели маршрутов при изменении `#address_to`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При выборе поисковых подсказок в input не срабатывает функция oninput, onchange](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/992380/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-input-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-oninput-onchange)