# При выборе поисковых подсказок в input не срабатывает функция oninput, onchange

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

При выборе поисковых подсказок в input не срабатывает функция oninput, onchange

```php
<main>
    <form action="index.php">
        <label for = "address_from">Откуда</label>
        <input class = "input" id="address_from" name="address_from" size="32" type="text" placeholder="Выберите место A">

        <label for = "address_to">Куда</label>
        <input class = "input" id="address_to" name="address_to" size="32" type="text" placeholder="Выберите место Б">
    </form>
    <div id="yandexMap" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
</main>
```

```js
$address_to = '';
$address_from = '';

$('#address_from').on('input', function(event){ 
    $address_from = ($(this).val())
    rute()
});


$('#address_to').on('input', function(event){ 
    $address_to = ($(this).val())
    rute()
});

function rute(){
    routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
        fromEnabled: true,
        from: $address_from,
        toEnabled: true,
        to: $address_to
     });
}

ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('yandexMap', {
    center: [55.355125, 86.087234],
        zoom: 11,
        controls: []
    }),
        routePanelControl = new ymaps.control.RoutePanel({
        });
    routePanelControl.routePanel.options.set({
        types: {auto: true}
    });
    var _from = new ymaps.SuggestView('address_from');
    var _to = new ymaps.SuggestView('address_to');

    myMap.controls.add(routePanelControl).add(zoomControl);
};
```

Comment: Вопрос про `SuggestView` или про `RoutePanel`?

Comment: @flapenguin SuggestView, как я понял из-за присваивания vlaue не срабатывает oninput или onchange и нужно сделать триггер только не знаю как это реализовать

Answer (score 0):

SuggestView в вашем коде отрабатывает корректно. Но функция **rute()** не способна работать вне функции **init()**, поскольку оперирует методами API Яндекс.Карт, а именно **routePanelControl**.

Поместите первую половину кода в **function init() {...}** и выбор саджеста пробросится в панель маршрутизации. Порядок получится типа такого:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {

$address_to = '';
...
function rute(){
    routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
       ...
     });
}

var myMap = new ymaps.Map('yandexMap', {...}),
...
    myMap.controls.add(routePanelControl)
};
```

Рабочий (добавьте лишь свой apikey) некоторое время пример: https://jsfiddle.net/t6ecbpk4/